# what is the best way to include markdown in angular-meteor

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I would like to include `markdown` text as part of my template.
I am using `angular-meteor` and I see 2 alternatives:

- install a package of angular such as [angular-markdown-directive](https://github.com/btford/angular-markdown-directive)
- include a file without the `.ng.html` postfix and use meteor's markdown like this: `{{#markdown}}{{>innerPreview}}{{/markdown}}`

Is there other alternatives? will it work? which one is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created package `oshai:angular-marked` in atmosphere from [hypercube's package](https://github.com/Hypercubed/angular-marked). you can search for it in atmosphere.

Answer (score 1):

At one point I created my own directive using showdown, but then decided I wanted to get rid of it and just use what Meteor already came with.

First thing. I have an .html file I called `meteorTemplates.html`. I just place all of the meteor templates in here that I use. I only have 2 and they're small.

In any case. The template looks like this:

```
<template name="mdTemplate">
    {{#markdown}}{{md}}{{/markdown}}
</template>
```

Inside my controller I have:

```
$scope.my.markdown = '#Markdown';
```

According to [angular-meteor](http://angular-meteor.com/api/meteor-include) docs:

```
The meteor-include directive holds the Angular scope of the directive as the as Template.currentData of the Meteor template.
```

So, Template.currentData == $scope.

Then inside the template helper I'll use the Template.currentData() like $scope.

```
Template.mdTemplate.helpers({
    md: function() {
      return Template.currentData().getReactively('my.markdown');
    }
});
```

My ng.html file will look like:

```
<div id="markdown-preview">
    <meteor-include src="mdTemplate"></meteor-include>
</div>
```